# Best practice async base method signature

Tags: c#, async-await

I've been wondering about this for quite some time, but didn't find any clear answer to this problem.

We're working on a WPF application with Entity Framework (C#). We've got a generic base class for a list component with some methods, like LoadData.
Currently its signature is `abstract List<TItem> LoadData()`, which means you can't use async await in there without losing control of the execution flow (other methods could potentially start before LoadData finished, creating a race condition).
Entity Framework has an extension method `ToListAsync()` which asynchronously fetches the data. Pretty much every component would be able to use this inside of LoadData.
Therefore, this method is a great candidate to be refactored to a signature of `abstract Task<List<TItem>> LoadDataAsync()`.

However, there are other methods on the base class which aren't quite as straight forward. Most of the time they are overwritten, async isn't required. However, sometimes (like 1/20) it'd be very useful if the method would return `Task`/`Task<T>` instead of just `void`/`T`.
Every other time that'd mean I'd need to return `Task.CompletedTask`/to wrap the result of the method in a `Task.FromResult(result)`.
An example for this kind of method would be `abstract TItem AddItem(someParameters)`, which most of the time simply creates a new object with parameters from a form. Sometimes though, you need additional data from a database or something similar. In those cases you'd need the base methods' signature to be `abstract Task<TItem> AddItemAsync(someParameters)`. (Edit: this idea really sucks, for multiple reasons)

Is there any reason to prefer a signature without `Task` in situations where performance isn't a big issue? Those methods will only be called once per module, adding `Task` to the signature wouldn't have a big impact on performance.
Another idea would be to offer both a normal base method and an async one, but that'd result in a lot of bloat and is probably just a bad idea.

TL;DR: Is there any reason not to return `Task`/`Task<T>` (or `ValueTask<T>`) in base methods, even if async is rarely used in the actual implemetation and most of the time I'd have to return `Task.CompletedTask`/`Task.FromResult(result)`?

Comment: the point of tasks isn't about performance, but about seperating CPU-intensive work from nonCPU-work - in particular from IO. That just means that your current thread is able to do something instead of just waiting for a resource to finish loading.

Comment: You already seem to be aware that it's trivial to construct a `Task` should you need one. Are you also aware that wrapping async code with synchronous wrappers is generally frowned upon? E.g. the two alternatives you're considering aren't symmetric if implementations *may* be synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain yeah I know that. That's why I gave the example of loading data from the database, which is exactly that - an IO task.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not sure I understand what you mean. 
However, thinking about it the second suggestion sucks anyways.  
Wrapping async code in sync code - how'd you even do that? 
If you're talking about async void - I know that those are only intended for top level methods (events), I try to remove every one of those non top level async voids in our codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a method only *rarely* requires `async`, but frequently requires a return value (hence `Task<T>` instead of `Task`), then: `ValueTask<T>` is probably your friend. Unlike `Task<T>`, this doesn't require any allocation; for example:

```cs
public ValueTask<int> GetSomethingAsync(string key)
{
    if (cache.TryGetValue(key, out int value))
        return new(value); // or new ValueTask<int>(value) in older C#

    return SlowAsync(key);
}
private async ValueTask<int> GetSomethingAsync(string key)
{
    int value = ... await based code here
    cache[key] = value;
    return value;
}
```

There is, however, an important semantic change with `ValueTask[T]`: a `ValueTask[T]` *must* be awaited (or the result fetched) exactly once. Not zero times, not twice: *once*.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I should read more into ValueTasks.